# How can i put data outside of child in firebase, i having problem look like this

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i having an code look like this for uploading data inside realtime firebase

this is the realtime database look like i use code at below:

[image: this is the realtime database look like i use code at below]

```
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("DataKerja").setValue(tempatKerja);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Alamat").setValue(alamat);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("AlamatKtp").setValue(alamatKtp);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Nokontak1").setValue(noKontak1);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Nokontak2").setValue(noKontak2);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("KTP").setValue(imageKTP);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Pendukung").setValue(image2);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("DataPendukung").setValue (dataNasabah);
```

and i want to remove upload 1 data outside of the child that look like this

[So the last .child("DataPelanggan")is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdiHq.png)

and when i try to remove that into this

```
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("DataKerja").setValue(tempatKerja);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Alamat").setValue(alamat);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("AlamatKtp").setValue(alamatKtp);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Nokontak1").setValue(noKontak1);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Nokontak2").setValue(noKontak2);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("KTP").setValue(imageKTP);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).child("Pendukung").setValue(image2);
reference.child("Pending").child(currentDateandTime).setValue (dataNasabah);
```

all the other file was gone and become this in below

[image: Look Like this]

so how can i solve it?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code did exactly what you programmed it for. To replace the child `currentDateandTime`'s data with the new one `dataNasabah`.

Now, to keep the previous records and update/add new field, you use [`updateChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) which prevents overwriting the previous data.

To use it, you pass a `HashMap` containing the value/fields you want to add without affecting other children of the node.

Sample code snippet from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields):

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Although, this code is an example for updating multiple child nodes of the database, simultaneously, which is why it's passing the child paths as string in the `put()`. But, for your use, you can change it to:

```
Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put(currentDateandTime, postValues);
reference.child("Pending").updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Comment: this `Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();` show Cannot resolve symbol `post`, i change the post into the data that i want to send?

Comment: but when i try to change to the DataNasabah, the toMap() say cannot resolve tomap in datanasabah

Comment: and when i try to create method in the DataNasabah that look like this 
` public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        return null;
    }`
and i try to debug it, if show in firebase for a sec and delete itself