# i've using startAt and endAt for getting range data, but i need to take data in another child inside the startAt

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to take data inside a folder of my Realtime Database that looks like this:

[image: this is the realtime database look like]

I have this code for getting the date range data and showing it in RecycleView .

```
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ( ).getReference ( );
        DatabaseReference pendingRef = db.child ("Users").child ("Pending");

        Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey ()
                .startAt ("*" + tanggalawal)
                .endAt ("*" + tanggalakhir + "\uf8ff");

        recView = (RecyclerView)findViewById (R.id.recview);
        recView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(queryByKey, Model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new MyAdapter (options);
        recView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

How can I get the DataPelanggan data inside of it?

Comment: *i want to take data inside an folder of my realtime database* Which one?

Comment: in DataPelanggan, im gonna take the currentDateandTime, date, fullName, nik, but after i took the data, im gonna put them into recycleview fragmnet

Comment: So you only want to get the value of `currentDateAndTime`, `date`, `fullName` and `nik` that exist inside DataPelanggan? If this what you want, I don't see any reason you have used a Query.

Comment: oh ya?, i don't know bout that cause i've been following some of youtube video of how to use startAt and endAt, what should i change to?, i've follow your way to search range data too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70077152/search-firebase-realtime-database-base-on-6-digit-in-front-of-the-child-data-i

Comment: So you followed that, and what's the issue?

Comment: it surely took data from the range, but im going to show the data at the recyleview. with the one i've using now is show blank on fragment, but when i manually put the data outside of DataNasabah folder, its work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the Firebase-UI library for Android, it means that the adapter will be able to display only a flat list of objects based on the query that you pass in, creating one ViewHolder object for each element.

Since your actual data is located beneath nodes like `DataPelanggan`, `KTP`, and so on, that library isn't really helpful. If you can change the database schema like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Pending
       |
       --- *20211127...
             |
             --- type: "DataPelanggan" 
             |
             --- currentDateAndTime: "*20211127..."
             |
             --- date: "16/10/1999"
             |
             --- fullName: "a"
             |
             --- nik: "4444...."
```

It will work because we have added the node key as a field right under each object. In this way, we removed that extra level in the schema and your code may remain unchanged.

Comment: i've tring to make sort of database look like that but i got problem with it,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225677/how-can-i-put-data-outside-of-child-in-firebase-i-having-problem-look-like-this this is the problem

Comment: No. Have you tried the solution in my answer?

Comment: well ofc it's work, but i cant arrange them into that look realtime databse

Comment: What is the order that you get? And what is the order that you want? I don't understand that.

Comment: i want to make a database look like your answer, but i need to put more child data inside there, how can i upload/add data without interfere the other file

Comment: Simply remove a call to something like this: `.child("DataPelanggan")`. In this way you will not create that extra level.

Comment: but well when i did that, the other folder will gone, its become replace by the non-child data

Comment: Without seeing the code and the database structure, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.